# HTTPS Site Accessed through IE but can not accessed through firefox

Tags: apache-2.2, web, firefox

Recently upgraded Apache version to 2.2.19, have done configuration (https) as usual, while trying to access the applications through IE its working fine.

But while trying to access through Firefox, it throws error as "Data Interrupted/Connection time out" , not even see update in access log and in netstat command it throws "TIME_WAIT"

Any one can share what is reason behind the accessibility through Firefox got interrupted.

Regards,
Siva

Comment: What does `tcpdump` say about the connections?

Answer (score 0):

In fuzzyfox config, check you allow "ssl 3.0" and the likes. Otherwise post the "view source" of the page in firefox that doesn't load, and any error logs you have. Good luck.

Comment: No Luck... But tried with the same configuration in different server, able to access in firefox .. But in particular server its not working .. Any ideas ...

Comment: I hope I'm not bringing this thread into a rude awakening from the dead, but yes. Do you by chance, on the failing server, have a rewrite mod or something that is selectively denying firefox?